# Return value from C function call?

Tags: c, function, while-loop

I'm currently reading Kernighan and Ritchie's *The C Programming Language* and ran into something I don't quite understand. In Chapter 4.1, this is mentioned to print only certain lines which contain a certain pattern:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#define MAXLINE 1000

int getlin(char line[], int max); /* getline() used in standard library */
int strindex(char source[], char searchfor[]);

char pattern[] = "ould";

int main()
{
    char line[MAXLINE]; 
    int found = 0;

    while (getlin(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
        if (strindex(line, pattern) >= 0) {
            printf("%s", line);
            found++;
        }
    return found;
}

int getlin(char s[], int lim)
{
    int c, i;

    i = 0;
    while (--lim > 0 && (c = getchar()) != EOF && c != '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    if (c == '\n')
        s[i++] = c;
    s[i] = '\0';
    return i;
}

int strindex(char s[], char t[])
{
    int i, j, k;
    for (i = 0; s[i] != '\0'; i++) {
        for (j = i, k = 0; t[k]!='\0' && s[j] == t[k]; j++, k++)
            ;
        if (k > 0 && t[k] == '\0')
            return i;
    }
    return -1;
}
```

Sorry, I realize it's long, but it's relatively straightforward. My only issue with this is on the 9th line - `while (getlin(line, MAXLINE) > 0)`. I'm not clear on whether this is referring to the `i` the function returns or the actual `int getlin()` itself, in which case how would the while-loop ever stop, or a better question might be where is the value of it modified.

Comment: Your question is very odd. Are you confusing `getlin(line, MAXLINE)`, which is a call of getlin that yields a value, with `&getlin`, which is the location of the function in memory? Your " the actual int getlin() itself" sort of suggests that.

Answer (score 3):

```
while (getlin(line, MAXLINE) > 0)
```

This code executes the `getlin()` function and checks its return value. If the return value is positive, the loop continues, otherwise the loop exits.

`getlin()` appears to return the length of the line read (number of characters) or zero if the end of the file has been reached. Thus, the loop will continue reading lines until there are no more lines to read.

Answer (score 0):

That line will execute the `getlin` method and check against the return value.